# How can i achieve slide to delete feature in cordova?

Tags: angular, cordova, mobile, cordova-plugins

I've converted my angular 4 app to Cordova recently and now i want to add some native functionality. One which I need is slide/swipe any list item to show delete option. 
You can get the idea from gif below.
Should I do it in angular instead or Cordova?

Slide to delete Gif

[image: Slide to delete Gif]

Comment: are you want to convert it to ionic1.x or ionic 2.x .....

Comment: No. I already convert it to cordova. Now need any module for angular or cordova which can do this swipe to delete for me.

Comment: @rahul shukla give you angularjs solution and <ion-content> is ionic element...

Comment: yes, but i need either angular or cordova solution, not ionic one.

Comment: Got any solution ?

Comment: @Upendra not yet. I've to choose other way to achieve this kind of stuff. Which we did by changing in design but wasn't good enough but we've to go with that.

Answer (score 0):

```
use this:

angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.data = {
    showDelete: false
  };

  $scope.edit = function(item) {
    alert('Edit Item: ' + item.id);
  };
  $scope.share = function(item) {
    alert('Share Item: ' + item.id);
  };

  $scope.moveItem = function(item, fromIndex, toIndex) {
    $scope.items.splice(fromIndex, 1);
    $scope.items.splice(toIndex, 0, item);
  };

  $scope.onItemDelete = function(item) {
    $scope.items.splice($scope.items.indexOf(item), 1);
  };

  $scope.items = [
    { id: 0 },
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2 },
    { id: 3 },
    { id: 4 },
    { id: 5 }
  ];

});

html:
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
      <div class="buttons">
        <button class="button button-icon icon ion-ios-minus-outline"
          ng-click="data.showDelete = !data.showDelete; data.showReorder = false"></button>
      </div>
      <h1 class="title">Ionic Delete/Option Buttons</h1>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button class="button" ng-click="data.showDelete = false; data.showReorder = !data.showReorder">
            Reorder
        </button>
      </div>
    </ion-header-bar>

    <ion-content>

      <!-- The list directive is great, but be sure to also checkout the collection repeat directive when scrolling through large lists -->

      <ion-list show-delete="data.showDelete" show-reorder="data.showReorder">

        <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items" 
                  item="item"
                  href="#/item/{{item.id}}" class="item-remove-animate">
          Item {{ item.id }}
          <ion-delete-button class="ion-minus-circled" 
                             ng-click="onItemDelete(item)">
          </ion-delete-button>
          <ion-option-button class="button-assertive"
                             ng-click="edit(item)">
            Edit
          </ion-option-button>
          <ion-option-button class="button-calm"
                             ng-click="onItemDelete(item)">
            Del
          </ion-option-button>
          <ion-reorder-button class="ion-navicon" on-reorder="moveItem(item, $fromIndex, $toIndex)"></ion-reorder-button>
        </ion-item>

      </ion-list>

    </ion-content>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. That swipe-to-delete module isn't what i needed. Like I can also put delete and edit options. When i swipe it, it should show options instead of full swipe to delete.

Comment: ok means you need a slider function that deletes the value when we swipe it right

Comment: No, it should show me option to delete it when i swipe. You can see it in the gif i shared in question.

Comment: ok let mee try .. well for your question  Should I do it in angular instead or Cordova? my suggestion you should prefer going with angular.

Comment: Yes, i was thinking that too. Is there any other module available?

Comment: ya i was checking the codova native transitions for the same https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-native-transitions you can also check if you find it handy

Comment: I don't think it can be achieved with this plugin

Comment: check the code i edited this wht i guess you exactly want.

Comment: this code is for ionic, need angular or cordova option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167241/discussion-between-rahul-shukla-and-inzimam).